# React-native FBSDK with rails omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, omniauth-facebook, react-native-fbsdk

In rails omniauth-facebook, it requires a `signed_request` or a `code` as 
 params in `auth/facebook/callback?`

However, my problem is I can only get `AccessToken` from `react-native fbsdk` in app only, I tried using `code: accessToken` and `signed_request: accessToken`, but they doesn't seem fit, as I get this error

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, {"message"=>"Invalid verification code format.", "type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>100,
```

I tried passing `access_token: accessToken` but it returns

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! no_authorization_code: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::NoAuthorizationCodeError, must pass either a `code` (via URL or by an `fbsr_XXX` signed request cookie)
```

Any idea how can I get `signedRequest` or a `code` from react-native fbsdk? Or how can I use `access_token` in omniauth-facebook?

Comment: The target of callback step is getting `accessToken`.

Since you already done everything on your client with `FBSDK`, then just push user information to the server and let him logged in.